# Backup-SPFarm is not progressing for around 40 minutes. latest stage is "Verbose: [IndexController] Waiting for second phase backup for index "

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, administration, backup, sharepoint-farm

I have the following:-

1. sharepoint farm 2013 on-premises.
2. i have the following `back.bat` file:-

> "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Command
>   Start-Process "$PSHOME\powershell.exe" -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList
>   "'%~dp0\backup.ps1'"

3. and the following `backup.ps1` file which is being referenced from the above `.bat` file. and the .ps1 file will be doing a farm backup:-

> Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
>
> Remove-Item -recurse c:\Back*
>
> Backup-SPFarm -Directory  \***\Back -BackupMethod full -BackupThreads 10 -Force

4. now using the windows task scheduler, i create a task which will run the above `.bat` file.

now i have noted when the tasks started a new folder is created under the `c:\back` folder and the backup folder contain many `.bak` files with sizes such as 500 MB,150 MB, etc..
but for more than 40 minutes the backup task is not doing anything, and when i checked the `spbackup` file i find that it hangs on the following stage:-

```
Waiting for second phase backup for index SPd1f9d427e849.
```

here is the latest lines inside the `spbackup` file:-

```
[25/07/2017 17:03:55] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_bf83ad956c814b1fae127f1ce44962d0] 84 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:55] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_bf83ad956c814b1fae127f1ce44962d0] 91 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:55] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_bf83ad956c814b1fae127f1ce44962d0] 98 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:55] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_LinksStoreDB_5777fdbc964c4ab28cb7b4a29f84fbae] 14 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:55] Verbose: [Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_bf83ad956c814b1fae127f1ce44962d0] SQL Server Message: Processed 112 pages for database 'Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_bf83ad956c814b1fae127f1ce44962d0', file 'Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_bf83ad956c814b1fae127f1ce44962d0' on file 2.
[25/07/2017 17:03:55] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_bf83ad956c814b1fae127f1ce44962d0] 100 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:55] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_LinksStoreDB_5777fdbc964c4ab28cb7b4a29f84fbae] 28 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:55] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_LinksStoreDB_5777fdbc964c4ab28cb7b4a29f84fbae] 42 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:55] Verbose: [Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_bf83ad956c814b1fae127f1ce44962d0] SQL Server Message: Processed 2 pages for database 'Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_bf83ad956c814b1fae127f1ce44962d0', file 'Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_bf83ad956c814b1fae127f1ce44962d0_log' on file 2.
[25/07/2017 17:03:55] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_LinksStoreDB_5777fdbc964c4ab28cb7b4a29f84fbae] 56 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:55] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_LinksStoreDB_5777fdbc964c4ab28cb7b4a29f84fbae] 70 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:55] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_LinksStoreDB_5777fdbc964c4ab28cb7b4a29f84fbae] 84 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:55] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_LinksStoreDB_5777fdbc964c4ab28cb7b4a29f84fbae] 98 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:55] Verbose: [Search_Service_Application_LinksStoreDB_5777fdbc964c4ab28cb7b4a29f84fbae] SQL Server Message: Processed 56 pages for database 'Search_Service_Application_LinksStoreDB_5777fdbc964c4ab28cb7b4a29f84fbae', file 'Search_Service_Application_LinksStoreDB_5777fdbc964c4ab28cb7b4a29f84fbae' on file 2.
[25/07/2017 17:03:55] Verbose: [Search_Service_Application_AnalyticsReportingStoreDB_e3be102b34884efbb8fada7b1169d759] SQL Server Message: BACKUP DATABASE WITH DIFFERENTIAL successfully processed 41 pages in 0.063 seconds (5.084 MB/sec).
[25/07/2017 17:03:55] Verbose: [Search_Service_Application_AnalyticsReportingStoreDB_e3be102b34884efbb8fada7b1169d759] SQL command completed at: 25/07/2017 17:03:55.
[25/07/2017 17:03:55] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_LinksStoreDB_5777fdbc964c4ab28cb7b4a29f84fbae] 100 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:55] Verbose: [Search_Service_Application_LinksStoreDB_5777fdbc964c4ab28cb7b4a29f84fbae] SQL Server Message: Processed 1 pages for database 'Search_Service_Application_LinksStoreDB_5777fdbc964c4ab28cb7b4a29f84fbae', file 'Search_Service_Application_LinksStoreDB_5777fdbc964c4ab28cb7b4a29f84fbae_log' on file 2.
[25/07/2017 17:03:55] Verbose: [Search_Service_Application_LinksStoreDB_5777fdbc964c4ab28cb7b4a29f84fbae] SQL Server Message: BACKUP DATABASE WITH DIFFERENTIAL successfully processed 57 pages in 0.038 seconds (11.718 MB/sec).
[25/07/2017 17:03:55] Verbose: [Search_Service_Application_LinksStoreDB_5777fdbc964c4ab28cb7b4a29f84fbae] SQL command completed at: 25/07/2017 17:03:55.
[25/07/2017 17:03:55] Verbose: [Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_bf83ad956c814b1fae127f1ce44962d0] SQL Server Message: BACKUP DATABASE WITH DIFFERENTIAL successfully processed 114 pages in 0.114 seconds (7.756 MB/sec).
[25/07/2017 17:03:55] Verbose: [Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_bf83ad956c814b1fae127f1ce44962d0] SQL command completed at: 25/07/2017 17:03:55.
[25/07/2017 17:03:55] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d] 8 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:55] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d] 11 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:55] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d] 20 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:56] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d] 26 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:56] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d] 31 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:56] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d] 37 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:56] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d] 40 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:56] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d] 46 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:56] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d] 52 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:56] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d] 55 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:56] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d] 61 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:56] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d] 66 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:56] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d] 72 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:56] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d] 75 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:56] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d] 87 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:56] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d] 90 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:56] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d] 95 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:56] Verbose: [Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d] SQL Server Message: Processed 272 pages for database 'Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d', file 'Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d' on file 2.
[25/07/2017 17:03:56] Progress: [Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d] 100 percent complete.
[25/07/2017 17:03:56] Verbose: [Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d] SQL Server Message: Processed 4 pages for database 'Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d', file 'Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d_log' on file 2.
[25/07/2017 17:03:56] Verbose: [Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d] SQL Server Message: BACKUP DATABASE WITH DIFFERENTIAL successfully processed 276 pages in 0.105 seconds (20.489 MB/sec).
[25/07/2017 17:03:56] Verbose: [Search_Service_Application_DB_37e97f6ff2624e0fa193eac35ae8f97d] SQL command completed at: 25/07/2017 17:03:56.
[25/07/2017 17:03:56] Verbose: [IndexController] Waiting for second phase backup for index SPd1f9d427e849.
```

so can anyone adivce what is causing this problem?
second question. what i can do now? is there any harm if i force the task to end (if there is not any harm , how i can end the task?)? or it is better to wait till the backup fails or raise a timeout ?

here is how my backup folder looks like:-
[image]

here is the current running tasks inside the task manager:-
[image]

After around 2 hours the backup completed with 12 errors, here is part of the errors :-

```
[25/07/2017 18:50:07] Verbose: [IndexController] Aborting backup job for index SPd1f9d427e849.
[25/07/2017 18:50:07] Verbose: [Search Service Application] Resuming crawls and feeding.
[25/07/2017 18:52:38] Verbose: [Search Service Application] Resuming crawls and feeding completed in 2.5 minutes.
[25/07/2017 18:52:38] Verbose: [Search Service Application] Resuming master merge.
[25/07/2017 18:55:08] Verbose: [Search Service Application] Resuming master mergex completed in 2.5 minutes.
[25/07/2017 18:55:09] FatalError: Object Search Service Application failed in event OnBackup. For more information, see the spbackup.log or sprestore.log file located in the backup directory.
    FaultException: Management called failed with System.InvalidOperationException: 'Second phase backup job SPd1f9d427e849->\\******1\Back\spbr0000\ does not exist. (The job is still in the first phase.)' at    at Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.IndexController.BackupService.ProgressSecondPhase(String handle)
   at Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.IndexController.IndexControllerManagementAgent.WrapCall[T](Func`2 original)
[25/07/2017 18:55:09] Debug: 
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.Admin.IIndexControllerManagementAgent.ProgressSecondPhase(String handle)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.BRIndexComponent.RetryWhileNoEndPoint[T](Func`2 action, SPBackupRestoreInformation args, Guid ssaId, TimeSpan retryTimeout)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.BRIndexComponent.RetryWhileNoEndPoint[T](Func`2 action, SPBackupRestoreInformation args, Guid ssaId, TimeSpan retryTimeout)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.BRIndexComponent.<>c__DisplayClass13`1.<RetryWhileNoEndPoint>b__12()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass5.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__3()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.BRIndexComponent.RetryWhileNoEndPoint[T](Func`2 action, SPBackupRestoreInformation args, Guid ssaId)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.BRIndexComponent.WaitPhaseComplete(SPBackupInformation args, Func`2 getProgress, Int32 sleepTime)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.BRIndexComponent.WaitSecondPhaseBackupComplete(SPBackupInformation args)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.TwoPhaseBackupHelper.WaitSecondPhaseBackupCompleteChildren(SPBackupInformation args)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.OnBackup(SPBackupInformation args)
```

Comment: is your search crawl is running?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP  now i have the incremental crawl running each 15 minutes .. but on other farms i have the same settings , and i have never face any problem when doing backup-spfarm ... so are you saying that while doing backup-spfarm the search should not be running ? but i have been doing backup-spfarm on many farms over the years and i have never stop the search during the backup process.. can u adivce more on ur point please?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP now after 2 hours the backup completed with 12 errors!!

Comment: i am not saying stop the search service but i know if search crawl is running then it cause issue with backups

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP can you check my edit i provided the errors inside the backup process,, so the backup hangs for around 2 hours then i got the above errors ...

Comment: is the crawl running at that time? that what i am seeing

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP but this have been the case always.. i run the backup-spfarm when the search is running... so do you  mean i need to stop the search before doing the backup-spfarm? now as i mentioned i am scheduling the backup-spfarm using  windows task scheduler.. so not sure how i can force the sp search to stop before running the backup-spfarm??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62820/discussion-between-waqas-sarwar-mvp-and-john-g).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the error, what it looks like you are search crawl is running. if an active crawl is crawling the content then backup job will struggle to perform a backup.

Please make sure that search crawls are idle before backup job started.

read this here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepointsearch/2016/05/20/search-ssa-backup-is-failing-sp2013/

also https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748635.aspx